# map file directory from a java server to local machine

Tags: java, sockets, server

I have created a java server application which will take GET requests and return files to the browser. Also the files are downloaded to the directory using "content-disposition:attachment" in header.But this only downloads as files, I want to download as a folder and map it to a local directory. for example 
localhost:8080/xyz.jpg gives u an image .But localhost:8080/src/xyz.jpg should be downlaoded as src folder with an image in it eg: downloads/src/xyz.jpg. Currently if i do that ,it downloads as just a file. Since you guys asked.Here is the example code i used :) .thanks

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class myHTTPServer extends Thread {

    static final String HTML_START =
            "<html>" +
                    "<title>HTTP Server in java</title>" +
                    "<body>";

    static final String HTML_END =
            "</body>" +
                    "</html>";

    Socket connectedClient = null;
    BufferedReader inFromClient = null;
    DataOutputStream outToClient = null;


    public myHTTPServer(Socket client) {
        connectedClient = client;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            System.out.println( "The Client "+
                    connectedClient.getInetAddress() + ":" + connectedClient.getPort() + " is connected");

            inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (connectedClient.getInputStream()));
            outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectedClient.getOutputStream());

            String requestString = inFromClient.readLine();
            String headerLine = requestString;

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(headerLine);
            String httpMethod = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String httpQueryString = tokenizer.nextToken();

            StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            responseBuffer.append("<b> This is the HTTP Server Home Page.... </b><BR>");
            responseBuffer.append("The HTTP Client request is ....<BR>");

            System.out.println("The HTTP request string is ....");
            while (inFromClient.ready())
            {
                // Read the HTTP complete HTTP Query
                responseBuffer.append(requestString + "<BR>");
                System.out.println(requestString);
                requestString = inFromClient.readLine();
            }

            if (httpMethod.equals("GET")) {
                if (httpQueryString.equals("/")) {
                    // The default home page
                    sendResponse(200, responseBuffer.toString(), false);
                } else {
//This is interpreted as a file name
                    String fileName = httpQueryString.replaceFirst("/", "");
                    fileName = URLDecoder.decode(fileName);
                    if (new File(fileName).isFile()){
                        sendResponse(200, fileName, true);
                    }
                    else {
                        sendResponse(404, "<b>The Requested resource not found ...." +
                                "Usage: http://127.0.0.1:5000 or http://127.0.0.1:5000/</b>", false);
                    }
                }
            }
            else sendResponse(404, "<b>The Requested resource not found ...." +
                    "Usage: http://127.0.0.1:5000 or http://127.0.0.1:5000/</b>", false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendResponse (int statusCode, String responseString, boolean isFile) throws Exception {

        String statusLine = null;
        String serverdetails = "Server: Java HTTPServer";
        String contentLengthLine = null;
        String fileName = null;
        String contentTypeLine = "Content-Type: text/html" + "\r\n";
        String Content_disposition="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='src/fname.ext'";

        FileInputStream fin = null;

        if (statusCode == 200)
            statusLine = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + "\r\n";
        else
            statusLine = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" + "\r\n";

        if (isFile) {
            fileName = responseString;
            fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            contentLengthLine = "Content-Length: " + Integer.toString(fin.available()) + "\r\n";
            if (!fileName.endsWith(".htm") && !fileName.endsWith(".html"))
                contentTypeLine = "Content-Type: \r\n";
        }
        else {
            responseString = myHTTPServer.HTML_START + responseString + myHTTPServer.HTML_END;
            contentLengthLine = "Content-Length: " + responseString.length() + "\r\n";
        }

        outToClient.writeBytes(statusLine);
        outToClient.writeBytes(serverdetails);
        outToClient.writeBytes(contentTypeLine);
        outToClient.writeBytes(contentLengthLine);
        outToClient.writeBytes(Content_disposition);
        outToClient.writeBytes("Connection: close\r\n");
        outToClient.writeBytes("\r\n");

        if (isFile) sendFile(fin, outToClient);
        else outToClient.writeBytes(responseString);

        outToClient.close();
    }

    public void sendFile (FileInputStream fin, DataOutputStream out) throws Exception {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024] ;
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = fin.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fin.close();
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

        ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket (5000, 10, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
        System.out.println ("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 5000");

        while(true) {
            Socket connected = Server.accept();
            (new myHTTPServer(connected)).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be a good idea if you share some code, that would make easier for people to help you ;).

Comment: Don't invent the wheel: http://www.vonloesch.de/filebrowser.html

Comment: @Alex I am creating a server on my own to learn the intricacies and hav fun with it. Thats why i am inventing my own shiny little wheel :) , thanks for ur suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using the `HTTP` protocol and a normal browser, there is no MIME type for folders. Your browser is able to download only files.

If you want to do this through `HTTP`:

**Option 1:** Generate a "zip" file (or some other format that enables you to package a folder tree into a single file) which contains the folder tree and send that to the browser.

**Option 2:** Develop a custom client program that is able to interpret the response that it gets from the server and create the corresponding folders on the local filesystem.

Comment: Hmm thats what i was thinking too. I really did not want to create custom client to do this. I heard of inode/directory mime type somewhere but did not work much.

Comment: @Imprfectluck From what I know, `HTTP` doesn't have a MIME type for folders, maybe `inode/directory` is used by some other protocol.

Comment: Yup after long searching , it seems this seems to be the only way. So accepting this cos it helped me move on and create a client application to handle this :)

Comment: @Imprfectluck it seems that this is possible on Chrome using the [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) but this is a `JavaScript` implementation (client side).

Comment: yeah it is doable even in java using a client side approach. I wanted to do using just your everyday browser. I just wanted to know if i can do it without writing a client. But thanks for the link , it will help me in the next thing I am working on :D

Comment: I think i was asking the browser to do something that it was not designed to do. And server writing on its own is not possible as it would be a security breach to directly write onto the client side.